# How to return the entire list if filter is false

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have this list

```
List<String> lstStr = new ArrayList<>();
lstStr.add("1");
lstStr.add("2");
lstStr.add("3");
lstStr.add("4");
lstStr.add("5");
```

When I search for the string **"1"** its should return a `List<String> = ["1"]` and if search string is not in the list for example **"0"** it should return the entire `List <String> =["1","2","3","4","5"]`. Can this be achieved using java stream? Please show an example.

I have tried this using the code below but I could get the entire list when I search for say **"0"**

```
List<String> filteredLst = lstStr.stream()
                                  .filter(data-> "1".equalsIgnoreCase(data))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

filteredLst.forEach(data2 -> System.out.println(data2));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can partition on a predicate and return the non-empty list:

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> split = lstStr.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy("1"::equalsIgnoreCase));

List<String> filteredLst = split.get(Boolean.TRUE).isEmpty() ? 
                        split.get(Boolean.FALSE) : //can also use lstStr instead
                        split.get(Boolean.TRUE);
```

`Collectors.partitioningBy("1"::equals)` will return a 2-entry map, where `true` will be the key of entries that meet your filter, and `false` the key of the rest.

`filteredLst` should contain the value mapped to `true` if that is not empty, or the value of `false` otherwise (which would surely be the same as he original list)

Comment: Or just `List<String> filteredLst = split.get(!split.get(true).isEmpty());`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to handle duplicates then you can do the following :

```
static List<String> getOneOrAll(List<String> list, String element) {
    return list.stream()
               .filter(element::equalsIgnoreCase)
               .findFirst()
               .map(Collections::singletonList)
               .orElse(list);
}

...
List<String> result = getOneOrAll(lstStr, "1");
```

Otherwise you can pass in a predicate and filter the duplicates:

```
static <T> List<T> getOneOrAll(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    List<T> filteredList = list.stream()
                               .filter(predicate)
                               .collect(toList());
    return filteredList.isEmpty() ? list : filteredList;
}

...
List<String> result = getOneOrAll(lstStr, "1"::equals);
// or
List<String> resultIgnoringCase = getOneOrAll(lstStr, "1"::equalsIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `List.contains` does not have the same semantic as `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Comment: @Holger Yes, exactly. That's why the function accepts a generic `Predicate`. One day the OP may want to reuse the same function with different condition.

Comment: Your second solution does. Your first selects via `list.contains` check.

Comment: @Holger It makes sense. Updated the first solution. The only caveat is that `Arrays.asList(...)` returns an immutable list.

Comment: The list returned by `Arrays.asList` is not immutable. It still supports the `set` method. It just doesn’t support resizing, i.e. `add` and `remove` don’t work. But since there’s no specification about mutability, I’d say immutable would be fine, especially when the result may or may not be the original list, which rules out sensible application logic based on expected mutability. Therefore, you could also use `.map(Collections::singletonList)`, which returns a truly immutable (and more efficient) list.

Comment: @ETO `List::of` would be really immutable

Comment: @Eugene isn't it a `Java9`'s feature?

Comment: @ETO it is, yes

Answer (score 1):

A possible simple util for this would be using `contains` :

```
List<String> findAndReturnValue(List<String> lstStr, String value) {
    return lstStr.contains(value) ? Arrays.asList(value) : lstStr;
}
```

and for possible duplicates in the list:

```
List<String> findAndReturnValue(List<String> lstStr, String value) {
    return lstStr.contains(value) ?
            lstStr.stream()
                    .filter(a -> a.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) // condition as in question
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()) : lstStr;
}
```

To reduce the complexity for the cases where the element would be present in the list, the rather simpler solution would be collecting to a list and then checking for the size :

```
List<String> findAndReturn(List<String> lstStr, String value) {
    List<String> filteredLst = lstStr.stream()
            .filter(data -> data.equalsIgnoreCase(value))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return filteredLst.isEmpty() ? lstStr : filteredLst;
}
```

Comment: As with other answers, keep in mind that `List.contains` does not have the same semantic as testing via `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom Collector for this purpose.

```
li.stream().filter(d->"0".equalsIgnoreCase(d)).collect(
            Collector.of(
                    ArrayList::new,
                    ArrayList::add,
                    (a, b) -> {
                        a.addAll(b);
                        return a;
                    },
                    a -> a.isEmpty() ? li : a
            )
    );
```

Look for Collector docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html

Answer (score -1):

First Check if your list contains that value .
If yes then go for filtering the list
or else just print the Previous list

```
if(!lstStr.contains("0")) {
        lstStr.forEach(data2 -> System.out.println(data2));
    }else {
    List<String> filteredLst = lstStr.stream()
            .filter(data-> "1".equalsIgnoreCase(data))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    filteredLst.forEach(data2 -> System.out.println(data2));
    }
```